# Clipping: Image Offset when clipping raster in both Python and QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, raster, clip

I am trying to clip two raster with the same co-ordinates using Python. But even though they are from the same co-ordinates they are properly not align with each other. Its the same problem with QGIS 3.16.6 and also I tried with QGIS 2.8.7. The cell size for the image is 10,10 and 0.04,0.04 for the other one.Is it because of the mismatch of the cell size or something I am doing wrong. I can't understand what causing it how to fix.

[image]

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show
from rasterio.plot import show_hist
from rasterio.mask import mask
from shapely import geometry
from shapely.geometry import box
import geopandas as gpd
from fiona.crs import from_epsg
import pycrs
import pandas as pd 
import json
from shapely import speedups
speedups.disable()
df = pd.read_csv("coordinates.txt")

fp = r"resample_UAV.tif"
data = rasterio.open(fp)

i = 1
while True:
    minx = df.iloc[i][0]
    miny = df.iloc[i][1]
    maxx = df.iloc[i+1][0]
    maxy = df.iloc[i+1][1]
    bbox = box(minx, miny, maxx, maxy)
    geo = gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry': bbox}, index=[0], crs=from_epsg(32614))
    geo = geo.to_crs(crs=data.crs.data)
    def getFeatures(gdf):
        return [json.loads(gdf.to_json())['features'][0]['geometry']]
    coords = getFeatures(geo)
    out_img, out_transform = mask(dataset=data, shapes=coords, crop=True)
    out_meta = data.meta.copy()
    crs = from_epsg(32614)
    out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
                    "height": out_img.shape[1],
                    "width": out_img.shape[2],
                    "transform": out_transform,
                    "crs": crs}
                            )
    out_tif = r"{}.tif".format(i)
    
    with rasterio.open(out_tif, "w", **out_meta) as dest:
            dest.write(out_img)
    i += 1
    if i > (len(df)-2):
        break
```

I also tired with GDAl_translate but no improvement
Geotransform
For the images with cell size 0.04

```
Dimensions
X: 3454 Y: 3454 Bands: 4
Origin
690789,1.8704e+06
Pixel Size
0.04343,-0.04343
No Data Value
0 
Data Type
Byte - Eight bit unsigned integer
Pyramid overviews
Layer Spatial Reference System
+proj=utm +zone=14 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
Layer Extent (layer original source projection)
690788.9751400001114234,1870251.9970800001174212 :
690938.9823600001400337,1870402.0043000001460314

for the image with cell size 10
Dimensions
X: 15 Y: 15 Bands: 4
Origin
690785,1.87041e+06
Pixel Size
10,-10
No Data Value
0 
Data Type
Int16 - Sixteen bit signed integer 
Pyramid overviews
Layer Spatial Reference System
+proj=utm +zone=14 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
Layer Extent (layer original source projection)
690784.9840000000549480,1870258.6740900001022965 : 690934.9840000000549480,1870408.6740900001022965
```

Comment: what values are you clipping to? are they a multiple of both raster cell sizes? are both rasters centre coordinates or area coordinates?

Comment: Show the geotransforms for both rasters. The origins may have a slight offset.  gdalwarp can probably help there.

Comment: @wingnut i updated the question with the Geotransform

Comment: @IanTurton I take random points from the images and add 150 to x and subtract 150 to get 15 by 15 m. The both raster are area coordinates. i dont understand your second question

Comment: do your corner coordinates divide evenly by 0.4 and 10 in every case? otherwise you will get a rounding error

Comment: @IanTurton no i just use the same co-ordinates for both .Do you think that will cause the problem?

Comment: I would expect so - you won't get a part pixel in the output, running `gdalinfo` on the output will tell you for sure

Comment: The 10m array can't overlay the 4cm data with that origin. It has 10m pixel increments as your data shows. I would resample and clip the10m grid to 0.04m resolution with gdalwarp. You can use the nearest neighbour algorithm to keep the style of the original.